# Is x ⊆ S a well formed statement, when x is not a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let x be a object that is not a set

Let S be a set

Would the following statement:

x ⊆ S

evaluate to False, or considered not a well formed statement (as x is not even a set).

Comment: In Zermelo-Fraenkel Set Theory everything is a set. Which axioms are you using?

Comment: I'm not even sure. The only axioms I'm aware of in set theory is the law of Extensionality and Abstraction. I thought a set must be in curly brackets.

Comment: Informally, every set (that is, every object in set theory) is built up from the empty set $\emptyset$. For example, natural numbers are usually defined as
$0:=\emptyset$, $1:=\{0\}$, $2:=\{0,1\}=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$, $3:=\{0,1,2\}$, ...

Comment: Even if $x$ is a "class", the statement is well-formed:. The "verb" is $\subseteq$, which is a defined term, and the formula is shorthand for
$$\forall u\,(u\in x \to u\in S).
$$
When might $x$ (or $S$) not be a *set*? When it's a proper class -- a collection that's too "big" to be a set (too big to be a member of anything else). For example, with $X = \{c\mid c \text{is an infinite cardinal}\}, S = \{c\mid \text{c is a cardinal}\}$, the formula $X\subseteq S$ is shorthand for $\forall u\,(\text{$u$ is an infinite cardinal} \to \text{$u$ is a cardinal})$.

Comment: Even if we weren't using the set theory axioms that everything is a set, I'd say that is well-form.  $x \subseteq S$ is "x is a set of which all the elements are elements of S" is certainly well-formed and false.  But... since we almost certainly are using the set theory axioms the question is moot.

Answer (score 1):

In [Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory), i.e. the standard axioms of set theory, every "object" is a set. So a statement like $x\subseteq S$ will always make sense, and have the same value of truth as
$$
\forall z:z\in x\implies z\in S
$$

"Everything is a set" can be confusing. "What are numbers then?" someone may ask. For example, natural numbers can be constructed as sets as
$0:=\emptyset$, $1:=\{0\}=\{\emptyset\}$, $2:=\{0,1\}=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$, $3:=\{0,1,2\}=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\}$ *and so on...*

There other possible foundations for mathematics, like [type theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory), where there can be things that are not sets, so your question makes sense in that setting (but I do not know type theory).

Comment: Is there any other variations of theories?

Answer (score 1):

In the standard Axiomatic Set Theory of Zermelo-Fraenkel all objects (i.e., variables that you can quantify or constants you can use in formulas) are sets, so, in that case, a formula $x\subseteq S$ where $x$ is not a set makes little to no sense.

What some authors may do is extend the language to include symbols for classes (as done in Introduction to Axiomatic Set Theory by  Takeuti, G. and Zaring, W.M.), what must be clear is that you can't use any quantifier at those symbols, they represent collections of sets and are not objects in the strict sense, so, supposing that $x$ is a class but not a set, $x\subseteq S$ makes sense but would always be a false formula if $S$ is a set, because a set cannot have a proper class as a "subset" (or "subclass"), you can prove that aplying the Axiom of Separation to $S$ and having that $x$ is a set, thus a contradiction.